# Newbee, how to solve for t?

Tags: trigonometry

I haven't done math in 4 years now and I'm getting into Game programming. So I can't even remember where to start with this?
I would like to solve for t.

$x=16\left(\sin \left(t\right)\right)^3$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $1\over {16}$, then extract the cubic root on both sides. Finally apply the inverse of $\sin$ on both sides, that is, use $\arcsin$.

Comment: Is this correct?     $t=\sin \left(\left(\frac{x}{16}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Almost, the notation is usually $\sin^{-1}(\cdots)$ or $\arcsin(\cdots)$.

Comment: What you wrote is wrong, but I feel you got the right idea. To denote the inverse of $\sin$, if you're not using $\arcsin$, you should use $\sin ^{-1}$ and that would give you: $\displaystyle \sin ^{-1}\left(\left(\dfrac{x}{16}\right)^{1/3}\right)$.

Comment: I want to create the heart function which I calculated like so :  $y=13\cdot \cos \left(\arcsin \left(\left(\frac{x}{16}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\right)\space -\space 5\cos \left(2\cdot \arcsin \left(\left(\frac{x}{16}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\right)-2\cos \left(3\cdot \arcsin \left(\left(\frac{x}{16}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\right)\space -\cos \left(4\cdot \arcsin \left(\left(\frac{x}{16}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\right)\space $ but when I graph it using https://www.desmos.com/calculator it's only graphing half of it.

Comment: That's probably due to domains of the functions and such. can't help you right now, I'm off. Try asking a new question and link it to this one.

Comment: If your equation has one solution $t$, it has infinitely many.  You need some more restriction(s) on $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do some algebra: $\sin^{-1}({\frac{x}{16}})^{1/3}$

$x = 16 \sin^3(t)$

$\frac{x}{16} = \sin^3(t)$

$(\frac{x}{16})^{1/3} = \sin(t)$

$(\sin^{-1}(x/16))^{1/3} = t$

Comment: @anonymous:  you can put backslashes before functions to get the proper font, so \sin gives $\sin$ instead of $sin$.